# Create Asp.Net Core 2 project with database first and Individual identity

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an Asp.Net Core project after building my db schema, so db first.

I make the reverse engineering part, generating the code files via Package manager console. I replace the context with the new one I create from the command.

But everytime I try to run the Update-Database command I get and error. The last error it gives me is "The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined.".

Can someone please help me solve this and tell me a best practice how to work with db first and use asp.net identity with individual account too, to add all the required tables for it in the already existing db. Also if possible, to show how to update the models when I make changes on the db, also best possible and shortest way, without breaking too much code.

The identity tables and my tables should be in the same database and in the same context class. Also a critical point is to keep track of the changes on the db, so how to update the models accordly.

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: You will have to configure all entities in the context yourself, as there's no easy way to do this. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/src/EF) for the official code

Comment: @Fals after creating the db and its tables, I execute this command on the Package manager console: scaffold-dbcontext "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=MyReviewPortal;Integrated Security=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -context "PortalDbContext" -outputdir Data

Comment: But I get different errors when trying to run "update-database".

Comment: Primary Key is a must on a table in EF Core, So define a PK for `IdentityUserLogin` table first.

Comment: Refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: @viveknuna the migration code already has it